# Common neighbours of adjacent vertices in maximal planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/842/full.pdf?sequence=1

At the bottom of page 115 of the above it states that'By planarity one can verify that every vertex v of G
has at least one neighbor u such that u and v have exactly two neighbors in common.'

I have been able to prove this if the degree of the vertex is 5, but how would I go about proving it for all vertices in the graph?

Comment: Planarity in itself is not enough -- the graph of a cube (or dodecaedron) is planar, but no two neigboring nodes have any neighbors in common.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say maximal planar graphs. I will edit my question

Comment: Ah! The sentence _just before_ what you quote stipulates that $G$ is _triangular_.